# Mongodb: Find all documents where at least one array element does not matches?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a group document defined as this in Mongoose:

```
var GroupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    sections: [{type: ObjectId}]
});
```

As visible, group contains an array of sections. I also have another array of objectId's called **archived_sections**

I want to find all groups whose at least one section is NOT in archived_sections array. How to do that?

I was trying to use $nin operator like this:

```
Group.find({ sections: { $nin: archived_sections }).exec(function(err, groups){
  res.send(groups);
});
```

But this is giving me only those groups whose sections field holds an array with NO elements matching an element in the array archived_sections.

I want to find all groups where at LEAST ONE section is NOT in archived_sections array. How to achieve that? Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping your `$nin` in an [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) operator so that the `$nin` is applied separately to each element of `sections` instead of the set of elements as a group:

```
Group.find({ sections: { $elemMatch: { $nin: archived_sections } } })
    .exec(function(err, groups){
        res.send(groups);
    }
);
```

If at least one element satisfies the `$elemMatch` query, the doc matches.

Comment: Hello, I was trying to use the same for a value that is an ObjectId, such as `{ 'moves.player': { $elemMatch: { $ne: playerId } } }`, but receive `Error: Can't use $elemMatch with ObjectId.`, any idea how to circumvent the problem?

Comment: @Barnab It's best to post that as a new question.

Comment: Sure, did so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194129/mongodb-find-documents-with-array-where-at-least-one-element-does-not-match-obj)