# Mongodb: Find documents with array where at least one element does not match ObjectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am struggling with a MongoDB request. I have a `Play` schema that holds an array of `Move` objects. Each `Move` object holds a reference to a `Player` in the form of an ObjectID. Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729019/mongodb-find-all-documents-where-at-least-one-array-element-does-not-matches) I tried to do

```
{ 'moves.player': { $elemMatch : { $ne : playerId } } }
```

where `playerId` holds an ObjectID. However I get the error

```
Error: Can't use $elemMatch with ObjectId
```

I have also tried the following

```
{ 'moves.player.str': { $elemMatch : { $ne : playerId.toString() } } }
```

but it doesn't find the proper documents... Any ideas?

**Example**

Some `Play` records:

```
A = {
    "moves": [
        { player: { $oid: "56f32fe2f41638de3b3e4773" } },
        { player: { $oid: "56f32fe2f41638de3b3e4774" } }
    ]
}
B = {
    "moves": [
        { player: { $oid: "56f32fe2f41638de3b3e4773" } }
    ]
}
```

Query for `playerId = "56f32fe2f41638de3b3e4773"` should only return object A, since it is the only one that has an array of moves where at least one of the players is different from `56f32fe2f41638de3b3e4773`.

Comment: Unfortunately. Even though you found your own solution ( or at least you think you did ) this question does not show the document structure that you are in fact querying. Therefore it is of little use to anyone as an example, and is a very unclear question. Showing a sample document you expect to match would make it better.

Comment: Good suggestion, added an example, this might help understanding the problem. Was stuck on this one for a long time, so I suspect it could be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

OK, found out where the problem was... Just do

```
{ "moves": { $elemMatch: { "player": { $ne : playerId } } } }
```

and it works out fine!

Comment: Pretty sure that if your data looks like I "think" it does ( already told you it's not good to ask questions without a sample for others to solve the problem ) then simply `{ "moves.player": { "$ne": playerId } }` is enough. You only need `$elemMatch` when "two or more" conditions for properties need to be met. Single property inspection can be done with plain "dot notation".

Comment: `$ne` would not return the `Play` records where one of the `moves` was assigned to the player with `playerId`, so in my example wouldn't return neither A nor B...

Comment: Ah. Now I get it. Your answer is the right approach.